# Converting MIDI byte array to MP3 byte array

Tags: c#, .net, audio, lame

Does someone know how to convert a **MIDI file** (average playback time of 30 seconds) which is represented in a byte array to an **MP3 byte array**?

So, ideally I need to have a C# function which accepts a MIDI byte array and returns a MP3 byte array.

**The conversion should not take more than 2 - 3 seconds.**

Are there any frameworks / tools / 3rd-party DLLs to perform this easily?

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: You're aware you'll need a software synthesizer to do so? It can be the crappy one built into Windows though.

Comment: @ herzmeister der welten :Could you please provide resources, to understand the basics of programming audio conversion ?

Comment: As @Aliostad said, a MIDI file contains no audio. It contains instructions when to play which note with which volume (and other parameters). It's like automation for a music keyboard or another electronic instrument. The quality can differ enormously depending on which device is used. For more info see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI . Windows has such a "keyboard" "built in". It will generate the appropriate sounds when it reads a MIDI file and play it.

Comment: Thanks  herzmeister der welten

Comment: http://is.gd/igp4m -- I've seen soooo many questions about converting MIDI to audio I had to write this.  Please take the time to read it if you are considering writing some software system which needs to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Over at CodeProject there's a C# MIDI Toolkit which could help you](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx). You'll probably have write the code to record the output stream yourself though.

Comment: Thanks herzmeister der welten

Answer (score 2):

MIDI file is not audio, it is audio instructions. This has to be "rendered/played" to audio (using various MIDI players depending on the capability of your sound card) and then compressed to MP3.

I do not know a DLL that can do all of that. Lame MP3 DLL is a free open source DLL that can do the compression for you.

http://lame.sourceforge.net/